# After triggering how to get a 5 sec delay

Tags: jquery, html

Here is my question 
I am triggering a click for a particular function after this trigger I need 5 Sec delay before the next click click inside the condition here is my code

```
$('.history .enter').trigger('click');
if( peCount != 7) {
    $('.btn_physical').trigger('click');
    $('.black_bg').fadeIn(300);
}
```

Somebody please help.

Comment: Where is your click event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout), to put delay.

```
$('.history .enter').trigger('click');
if( peCount != 7) {
    $('.btn_physical').trigger('click');
    setTimeout(function(){
       $('.black_bg').fadeIn(300);
    }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure he wanted the trigger not the fade in :D

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: There was a type check it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `queue` and `delay`, be aware a delay cannot be reseted.

```
$('.btn_physical').clearQueue().delay(5000).queue(function(){$(this).trigger('click');});
```